# How to make clear INSERT like queries in Go sqlx?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, sqlx

I am having code below which has query constant `createOrderQuery`. This query simply inserts order to orders table. But there is a lot of boilerplate code in this query like
`$1, $2, $3, $4…`. Is there any way to remove this boilerplate to make code more clear?

By the way, I know how to do this with `sqlx.db.NamedExec()` method. But not see this method correlated with `sqlx.db.Begin()`.

```golang
const createOrderQuery = `
    INSERT INTO orders(order_id, user_id, cli_order_id, type, symbol, quantity, side, filled,
                      timestamp, last_update_timestamp, price)
    VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8,
                      $9, $10, $11)`

const createUsersOrdersQuery = `
    INSERT INTO users_orders(user_id, order_id) VALUES ($1, $2)
`

func (k *KrakenOrdersManagerPostgres) CreateOrder(userID int, order models.Order) error {
    tx, err := k.db.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    _, err = tx.Exec(createOrderQuery, order.ID, order.UserID, order.ClientOrderID, order.Type, order.Symbol, order.Quantity,
        order.Side, order.Filled, order.Timestamp, order.LastUpdateTimestamp, order.Price)
    if err != nil {
        if err := tx.Rollback(); err != nil {
            return ErrCouldNotRollbackTransaction
        }
        return err
    }

    if _, err = tx.Exec(createUsersOrdersQuery, userID, order.ID); err != nil {
        if err := tx.Rollback(); err != nil {
            return ErrCouldNotRollbackTransaction
        }
        return err
    }

    return tx.Commit()
}
```

Comment: this one is a cool package to deal with boilerplate https://github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [github.com/Masterminds/squirrel](https://github.com/Masterminds/squirrel) package:

```
import sq "github.com/Masterminds/squirrel"

...

sql, args, err := sq.
Insert("orders").Columns("order_id", "user_id", "cli_order_id", "type", "symbol", "quantity", "side", "filled", "timestamp", "last_update_timestamp", "price").
Values(order.ID, order.UserID, order.ClientOrderID, order.Type, order.Symbol, order.Quantity,
    order.Side, order.Filled, order.Timestamp, order.LastUpdateTimestamp, order.Price).
ToSql()

 _, err = tx.Exec(sql, args...)
...
```